# I can't get my output to show all the security groups an AD user is a member of

Tags: powershell, active-directory, formattable

So I'm trying to do a seemingly simple task and even though I've been working with powershell for a while now, I don't use it everyday so I get rusty quick. Anyway, I'm trying to poll every user in an AD and find out what security groups they are a member of. I'm 90% of the way there except for one problem.

First, my code so far:

```
$users = (Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=contoso,DC=com").samaccountname | Sort-Object

foreach ($user in $Users) {
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user

    $obj = new-object psobject -Property @{
        Username        = $user
        GroupMembership = $groups.samaccountname
    }
    $obj | Format-Table Username, GroupMembership -auto
}
```

The problem I have is the output when there are more than 2 or 3 groups, I get an ellipsis:

```
Username      GroupMembership                                                
--------      ---------------                                                
administrator {Domain Users, Administrators, Domain Admins, Schema Admins...}

Username GroupMembership                                                
-------- ---------------                                                
dhcpbind {Domain Users, Administrators, Domain Admins, Schema Admins...}
```

I can't get it to show, all the users on a single line. I've tried auto-sizing, wrap, -width, and every other conceivable thing my tiny brain can come up with. I've been googling and trying things for a while now and I really just need some direction. I'm sure it's something simple but I am simply not versed enough to know what to do.

My other issue is it puts a title over each user object, my guess there is because it is in the loop and I could maybe solve that on my own but if the solution could include that, I would appreciate it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Set `$formatenumerationlimit = -1`. The default value is `4`

Comment: Well I'll be, that did it, thank you sir or madam! I envy your abilities.